# In-place resequence of a primary-key column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have a table with a composite primary key:

```
table MyTable 
(
    some_id smallint not null,
    order_seq smallint not null,
    --other columns
)
```

...where `some_id` and `order_seq` make up a composite primary key. The `order_seq` column is used to determine the display order in other parts of my C# 3.5/ASP.NET application.

I'm setting up an admin page where users can shuffle these rows around, changing multiple rows' `order_seq` values at a time:

[image: screenshot]

**All items on the screen have the same `some_id`.** When the user clicks Submit, the new `order_seq` values are supposed to be saved to the database.

My problem is that `order_seq` is part of the PK, so the task of shuffling these things around becomes complicated. Since `some_id` is the same, I have no way of identifying them other than `order_seq` itself, which changes as I go. Furthermore, I have to make sure the `order_seq` values stay unique (presumably with some kind of temp value).

The best idea I have is to use some kind of in-memory collection to keep track of the changes I've made so far. I'm having trouble implementing it, though. How can I do an in-place resequence of multiple rows at once? I'd be fine with either a C# or SQL-based solution.

**EDIT: Unfortunately, I have zero control over the table design,** and limited control over the DB in general. I won't be able to change the PK scheme or introduce any new columns.

Comment: Does it _have_ to be a composite PK?

Comment: Have to throw it out there, what about just axing the composite key entirely and just dropping a guid column in and then using those as lookups instead of PKs?

Comment: Even an identity column would make life easier for you.

Comment: @Oded, @Chris and @Matthew - I'd love to have a separate identity column, or for this not to be a PK, but I have no control over the table design. :-/

Comment: @Justin Morgan - Then what about creating another table with a 1:1 relationship that stores the sort order?

Comment: @Thomas - My DB control is pretty limited, but I could create a temp table inside a stored procedure...it's a possibility.

Comment: @Justin Morgan - That wont work. What you need is storage for the sort order separate from the PK. Right now, you are trying to use the PK both to dictate sequence and to uniquely identify each row. What you need is to separate those two concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If at all possible, you will save yourself a lot of stress if you introduce a surrogate primary key. Since you can change the order_seq without changing any of the other fields, it's doesn't really fit as part of the primary key (which all other fields in your record should directly depend on). But even beyond the theoretical stuff, you're already discovering the technical problems with this kind of compound key.

If you do need to keep the structure the same, then changing the key fields is going to be tedious and, as you already figured out, require some temporary values. Off the top of my head, if I had to accomplish this I'd do it in two steps:

```
UPDATE Table SET order_seq = @newval + BIG_OFFSET WHERE order_seq = @oldval

UPDATE Table SET order_seq = order_seq - BIG_OFFSET WHERE order_seq > BIG_OFFSET
```

Obviously, run the first statement for every distinct row that's changing, then run the second statement at the very end to reset their values. This should prevent you from having duplicate primary keys at any point in the process.

Comment: I've tried something similar with setting `order_seq = @newval * -1`, but I get a PK violation error. Changing multiple `order_seq` columns at once seems to cause a problem.

Comment: When I posted this question, I *thought* I had already tried this method and failed, but there must have been something else going on. I ended up setting `order_seq = order_seq * -1 where some_id = @some_id`, then setting everything to the new values based on that. It's basically the same as this, but it avoids the chance of overflow (potentially an issue, depending on the offset). This is the closest to what I used, so I'm accepting (and upvoting) it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store the original composite PK (hidden column). On the screen, if you manage it properly, two items should not have the same order. Then you can find the items with the original composite PK and update them with your new order values.

Edit: All right, you can do similar thing in your code, ie, keep track of the list of objects with original PK and current PK, any time user tries to change order, do a validation if it's allowed, and then either allow or block it. You'll need to find an object with updated Id and orderId, if you do find one, then it's not allowed. 
Sorry, if I haven't understood the problem. Trying to help.

Comment: I've done that, it's just that I need to change multiple rows at once. When I change one, I need some way to keep track of it for later, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Re: your edit -- I was thinking that's what I would have to do if I didn't find a simpler solution to the problem. It would've meant less risk of leaving junk temporary data in the DB, but I took a shot at coding it and it seemed pretty complicated. +1 though, it's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a SP that takes a XML parameter with a pair of the old order_seq and the new order_seq.

Some test data

```
create table MyTable
(
  some_id int,
  order_seq int,
  name varchar(10)
  primary key(some_id, order_seq)
)

insert into MyTable values
(1, 1, '1_1'),
(1, 2, '1_2'),
(1, 3, '1_3'),
(1, 4, '1_4'),
(2, 1, '2_1'),
(2, 2, '2_2')
```

Stored proc

```
create procedure SetOrder
  @some_id int,
  @new_order xml
as

;with cte as
(
  select 
    X.N.value('@OldSeq', 'int') as OldSeq,
    X.N.value('@NewSeq', 'int') as NewSeq
  from @new_order.nodes('/i') as X(N)
)  
update T
  set order_seq = C.NewSeq
from MyTable as T  
  inner join cte as C
    on T.order_seq = C.OldSeq
where T.some_id = @some_id
```

To reverse the order for `some_id = 1` call the SP like this:

```
exec SetOrder 1, 
  '<i OldSeq="1" NewSeq="4"/>
   <i OldSeq="2" NewSeq="3"/>
   <i OldSeq="3" NewSeq="2"/>
   <i OldSeq="4" NewSeq="1"/>'
```

You need to keep track of the old order_seq on the client and build the xml when the user chooses to submit the changes.

Comment: I like this method. I managed to solve this particular problem in a different way, but this feels better and less hackish than what I had to use, so I'll remember it. +1 and thanks.